# How to set image position and image size in PPT in C# (Aspose)?

Tags: c#, aspose-slides

I want to move image position and want to set image size in PPT in C# which uses Aspose.slides. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Hello Sagar, and welcome to SO.  Please edit your question to include citations of code you have tried and and error messages or unexpected results that you received while trying those methods.

Answer (score 1):

i am going to cite the [doc](https://docs.aspose.com/display/slidesnet/Shape+Manipulations#ShapeManipulations-PictureFrameFormatting)

```
// The path to the documents directory.
string dataDir = RunExamples.GetDataDir_Shapes();

// Create directory if it is not already present.
bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(dataDir);
if (!IsExists)
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dataDir);

// Instantiate Presentation class that represents the PPTX
using (Presentation pres = new Presentation())
{

    // Get the first slide
    ISlide sld = pres.Slides[0];

    // Instantiate the ImageEx class
    System.Drawing.Image img = (System.Drawing.Image)new Bitmap(dataDir+ "aspose-logo.jpg");
    IPPImage imgx = pres.Images.AddImage(img);

    // Add Picture Frame with height and width equivalent of Picture
    IPictureFrame pf = sld.Shapes.AddPictureFrame(ShapeType.Rectangle, 50, 150, imgx.Width, imgx.Height, imgx);

    // Apply some formatting to PictureFrameEx
    pf.LineFormat.FillFormat.FillType = FillType.Solid;
    pf.LineFormat.FillFormat.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.Blue;
    pf.LineFormat.Width = 20;
    pf.Rotation = 45;

    //Write the PPTX file to disk
    pres.Save(dataDir + "RectPicFrameFormat_out.pptx", SaveFormat.Pptx);
}
```